# Tweepy: Filtering stream gives multiple errors

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to run the following script from this tutorial [tulane.edu-twitter](http://www.tulane.edu/~howard/CompCultES/twitter.html) and I'm getting the following errors:

```
  File "GetTextFromTwitter.py", line 61, in <module>
    stream.filter(track=['de'], languages=['es'])
  File "/Users/enricok/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 428, in filter
    self._start(async)
  File "/Users/enricok/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 346, in _start
    self._run()
  File "/Users/enricok/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 239, in _run
    verify=self.verify)
  File "/Users/enricok/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 465, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Users/enricok/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 573, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/enricok/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 370, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/Users/enricok/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 544, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/Users/enricok/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 349, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/Users/enricok/anaconda/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 995, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/Users/enricok/anaconda/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1029, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/Users/enricok/anaconda/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 991, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/Users/enricok/anaconda/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 848, in _send_output
    self.send(message_body)
  File "/Users/enricok/anaconda/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 820, in send
    self.sock.sendall(data)
  File "/Users/enricok/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 208, in sendall
    sent = self._send_until_done(data)
  File "/Users/enricok/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 198, in _send_until_done
    return self.connection.send(data)
  File "/Users/enricok/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 947, in send
    raise TypeError("data must be a byte string")
TypeError: data must be a byte string
```

I also tried to follow the tutorial on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pUUxmvvl2FE&spfreload=10) and I'm getting the same errors:

```
 File "tweepyTest.py", line 39, in <module>
    twitterStream.filter(track=["car"])
  File "/Users/enricok/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 428, in filter
    self._start(async)
  File "/Users/enricok/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 346, in _start
    self._run()
  File "/Users/enricok/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 239, in _run
    verify=self.verify)
  File "/Users/enricok/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 465, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Users/enricok/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 573, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/enricok/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 370, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/Users/enricok/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 544, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/Users/enricok/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 349, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/Users/enricok/anaconda/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 995, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/Users/enricok/anaconda/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1029, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/Users/enricok/anaconda/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 991, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/Users/enricok/anaconda/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 848, in _send_output
    self.send(message_body)
  File "/Users/enricok/anaconda/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 820, in send
    self.sock.sendall(data)
  File "/Users/enricok/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 208, in sendall
    sent = self._send_until_done(data)
  File "/Users/enricok/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 198, in _send_until_done
    return self.connection.send(data)
  File "/Users/enricok/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 947, in send
    raise TypeError("data must be a byte string")
TypeError: data must be a byte string
```

A couple of days ago it worked perfectly (still having the .csv it returned). But now like with an other script I tried, it gives me multiple errors when using the `.filter` method. If I replace `.filter()` with `.sample()` though, it works. The only thing I can remember, was doing a `brew update` that might have broken something.
Here the code for the first mentioned tutorial that tries to filter Spanish tweets.
Any ideas how to fix this?

```
import tweepy
import requests

from tweepy import API
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener

API_KEY = ''
API_SECRET = ''
ACCESS_TOKEN = ''
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = ''

key = tweepy.OAuthHandler(API_KEY, API_SECRET)
key.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

api = tweepy.API(key)


class Stream2Screen(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def __init__(self, api=None):
        self.api = api or API()
        self.n = 0
        self.m = 20

    def on_status(self, status):
        print status.text.encode('utf8')
        self.n = self.n+1
        if self.n < self.m:
            return True
        else:
            print 'tweets = '+str(self.n)
            return False

stream = tweepy.streaming.Stream(key, Stream2Screen())
stream.filter(track=['de'], languages=['es'])
# stream.sample()
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a connection error.

Install pyOpenSSL.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyOpenSSL